# PostgresSQL / pgAdmin4 / dump server version mismatch

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

I tried to make a backup with Postgres 11.1 in pgAdmin4, but it failed. 
pgadmin displayed a window with

Status: Failed (exit code: 1).

> pg_dump:server version: 11.1; pg_dump: 10.5
>
> pg_dump: aborting because of server mismatch

I don't really understand it. Does pgadmin4 not know that I am using 11.1 and not 10.5?

**PROBLEM SOLVED - IN MY CASE.**

Go to

pgadmin < Preferences < Path <  Binary Path

The PostgreSQL Binary Path was set automatically to `$DIR/../runtime`

I changed the Path to my installed PostgreSQL Version `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin`

Comment: THANK YOU @black_hole_sun for going back and updating your question with the answer as I was going nuts trying to figure out WHY the newest version of PGAgmin4 which support v15 of the DB couldn't dump a v14.7 DB.  It was still using my v13 BIN..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pgAdmin is using PostgresSQL client v10, but your server is v11.

Since v10 cannot know how to correctly dump a v11 database, it refuses to try.

Use a more recent version of pgAdmin!

Comment: Thanks. For an answer.  I use the lastest Version of pgadmin4 v.3.6 (released Nov. 29, 2018). So then i install PostgresSQL10.0

Comment: Hmm, I'd be surprised if the latest version of pgAdmin 4 didn't support PostgreSQL v11. Perhaps it is accidentally picking up a wrong `pg_dump` that's somewhere on your `PATH`?

Comment: sorry, what you mean with PATH? Is it possible to choose different  PostgresSQL clients versions in pgAdmin?

Comment: I don't know enough about pgAdmin to answer that. Perhaps I should delete my answer, since it points out the immediate cause of the problem, but fails to explain *how* that can happen or what to do against it.

Comment: "Perhaps I should delete my answer," Identifying the problem is the first step for a good solution. No need to delete, Laurenz.

Comment: Alright. Now it worked. Go To -->  pgAdmin4 < Preferences < Path < Binary path. In my case the "PostgreSQL Binary Path" was set to "$DIR/../runtime" i changed it to the my installed version "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin"