# PostgreSQL / pgAdmin4 / dump server version mismatch using docker images

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-dump, pgadmin-4

My environment is using the following docker images:

postgres:11

dpage/pgadmin4

On a machine using unRaid for it's OS.

My issue is that I'm unable to backup anything on my postgres 11 server via pgadmin4. pgadmin4 returns the following error:

```
pg_dump: server version: 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1); pg_dump version: 10.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

There was a similar question asked here: [PostgresSQL / pgAdmin4 / dump server version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659113/postgressql-pgadmin4-dump-server-version-mismatch)

They resolved in by changing the bin path, however these are docker images, and I am unable to find standalone binary file for Postgres 11 for Linux.

There is a issue in relation to this exact problem, but it was rejected and closed: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3843

I'm looking for any assistance to get/replace the tools in pgadmin4 so it can properly talk to postgres11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution for now is to use the snapshot build of pgadmin4's docker image.

It had something to do the tools available in Alpine Linux's docker image at the time, according to Dave Page, the maintainer of pgadmin4's docker images. They were updated recently and used in the snapshot image's build.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever packaged the pgAdmin 4 you are using packaged it with a PostgreSQL v10 client.

So that's where you'll have to complain.

In this case it is obviously Dave Page.

The website of the Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/) suggests:

> Please report any issues through the pgAdmin support channels. See https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/

So I guess the correct channel is to subscribe to that mailing list and voice your complaint there.

Sorry that this is so complicated, but the various tools in the PostgreSQL universe are maintained by different, albeit somewhat related, groups, each of which has its own channels.

Comment: The issue linked above: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3843 is from pgadmin4 issue board. They've been made aware of the issue, but they've rejected and closed it, so it's unresolved. Apparently downgrading pgadmin4 works (Like, what?).
`At the moment, pgAdmin includes 10.5 binaries only. The current versions are 10.6 and 11.1.`

https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries
Postgres no longer offers binary packages from version 11.1 onwards, so I can't get the tools from them atm.

So I'm looking for a way to get the version 11.1 tools so I can point pgadmin4 to them.

Comment: The bug was closed because it was about the EDB installer rather than pgAdmin 4, so it should have been raised with EDB. I suggest that you raise a bug with the docker image, which is a different thing. EDB does not ship installers for 32-bit platforms any more, but that is unrelated.

Comment: Ah, I understand. That might explain why the older version worked, with it being shipped with it. I have opened an issue here: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4003 specifically for the docker version. 

I'm still seeking a workaround with sourcing the needed binary's though in the meantime.

Comment: You shouldn't use that redmine thing, but write to the mailing list. But maybe that will be good enough.

Comment: Dave Page(The one who does the pgadmin4 docker images)  responded there with this:
```The tools in pgAdmin are provided by the OS vendor in the Docker images. In this case, Apine Linux. They have recently been updated and 11.x is available in the snapshot builds and 4.3 (when released).```

Comment: Cool that it is going to be fixed. But that's still a bit of an excuse. Dave Page, a PostgreSQL core team member, should be able to add a new `pg_dump` executable and a `libpq.so` into the docker image...

Comment: True, but I didn't want to make him feel attacked by pointing out the the postgres-client package that has pg_dump in it has been in Arch Linux's repo(3.9 and up) since before version 4 of pgadmin4. Or by pointing out that he should have told the other guy who had issues about it as well. Or that I personaly don't like issues being resolved/rejected when there's a legitimate issue that does need to have some sort of resolution, even if it's temporary.

I made a answer response with the temporary solution, but I'd like to say thank you Laurenz, for your time and assistance.